# c++ project unable to call/pick up template constructor class causing LNK1120 and LNK2019

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lnk2019

I'm getting LNK1120 and LNK2019 Errors on VS 2013 express for Desktop. When I compiled it on g++ command line, it gives error as "undefined reference to Binary_tree::Binary_tree(std::string)".

I got all the includes. Here is my code:

```
**//Header File:**
template <typename Item>
class Binary_tree
{
    string File_Name;
    list<Item> arr_data;

public:
    Binary_tree(string fname);
    ....//More functions definitions.
};

**//BinaryTree.cpp file**
template <typename Item>
Binary_tree<Item>::Binary_tree(string fname)
{
    File_Name = fname;
    total = 0;
    root = nullptr;

    std::ifstream filestream(fname);
    string line;

    while (!filestream.eof())
    {
        filestream >> line;
        arr_data.push_back(line);
    }
}

**//Main.cpp File:**
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string file = "HeapQuestions.txt";
    Binary_tree<string> test(file);

    test.printArr();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have your template Binary_tree implemented in your header file? If not that is your problem.

Comment: @captain-obvlious, I just updated my question. I know why it's causing that problem but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The fix is to not implement your template in a cpp file. Move the implementation to the header.

Comment: @drescherjm, but the whole class uses template.. you want me to move all the function implementations in header file.

Comment: Yes. Read the duplicate about why template implementations must be in a header.